# Automapper not mapping between two objects (which are virtually the same for all intents and purposes)

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

Yes, this is ANOTHER "Automapper not mapping" question. Either something broke or I'm going the stupid way about it. I'm building a webapp with ASP.NET Core 2.1 using AutoMapper 3.2.0 (latest stable release at the time) though I have tested with 3.1.0 with no luck either.

**Question**

Simple object to be mapped to another. For the sake of testing and trials, these are now EXACTLY the same, yet still automapper gives:

AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
NotificationModel -> NotificationViewModel
ProjectName.Models.Dashboard.NotificationModel -> ProjectName.Models.Dashboard.NotificationViewModel

The strange thing is, I have previously mapped this model set 7 ways to sunday in the Startup.cs file with the only thing changing is my facial expression. Other maps work as indicated using similar, if not the same code for them.

**The Models**

NotificationModel.cs

```
public class NotificationModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateTS { get; set; }
        public bool FlagRead { get; set; }
        public bool FlagSticky { get; set; }
        public bool FlagReceipt { get; set; }
        public string ReceiptContact { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public bool CANCELLED { get; set; }
    }
```

NotificationViewModel.cs

```
public class NotificationViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //Reminder, this model has been amended to exactly represent that of the original model for testing purposes.
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateTS { get; set; }
    public bool FlagRead { get; set; }
    public bool FlagSticky { get; set; }
    public bool FlagReceipt { get; set; }
    public string ReceiptContact { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public bool CANCELLED { get; set; }        
}
```

**Startup & Automapper Config**

```
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
// Some other mappings removed for clarity.
                cfg.CreateMap<GroupViewModel, GroupModel>().ReverseMap();
                //cfg.CreateMap<EntityViewModel, EntityModel>().ReverseMap().ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());


                cfg.CreateMap<NotificationModel, NotificationViewModel>().ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
                cfg.CreateMap(typeof(NotificationViewModel), typeof(NotificationModel));
//I even left out the .ReverseMap, for testing purposes.
            });
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

**Usage**

`NotificationViewModel test = _mapper.Map<NotificationViewModel>(item); << Which` is where I receive the exception.

**Other Attempts**

Ok, so I've been through some more articles explaining different things and subsequently tried the following respectively:

```
cfg.CreateMap(typeof(NotificationModel), typeof(NotificationViewModel));
cfg.CreateMap<NotificationModel, NotificationViewModel>().ReverseMap().ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
cfg.CreateMap<NotificationModel, NotificationViewModel>().ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Along with:

```
NotificationViewModel test = _mapper.Map<NotificationViewModel>(item);
_mapper.Map(item, typeof(NotificationViewModel), typeof(NotificationModel));
NotificationViewModel existingDestinationObject = new NotificationViewModel();
                _mapper.Map<NotificationModel, NotificationViewModel>(item, existingDestinationObject);
```

I've tried amending the .Map()/.Map<> usage several ways, none of which seemed to yield anything but an exception about not having been configured.

So short of manually writing a conversion for this object (which is simple enough for its purpose), I am in dire need of a solution here. If not to use, then atleast to learn from and help others facing the same.

**UPDATE**

IT WORKS!

Scanning through the project, I noticed that somewhere in previous documentation - I read about creating a type of "config" class that just inherits from an abstract class called Profile. In this class you will also be able to define your maps, yet what is strange is that I am not able to drop this class and simply use the config maps setup in my Startup.cs file. Automapper will refuse to hold any maps that are not defined in this separate class. The below seems to get me what I need, however I still need an explanation as to why Automapper doesn't function as desired without it:

```
public class AMConfig : Profile
{
    public AMConfig()
    {
        CreateMap<ManageUserModel, IndexViewModel>();
        CreateMap<IndexViewModel, ManageUserModel>();
        CreateMap<NotificationViewModel, NotificationModel>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<List<NotificationViewModel>, List<NotificationModel>>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<TaskViewModel, TaskModel>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you use `Mapper.Map<NotificationViewModel>(item)`?

Comment: Nope, _mapper is the DI object I have to use to interact with Automapper. Plus again. this works in other controllers.. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The reason I asked is that it seems you're configuring the *static* Mapper and then using a *non-static* Mapper, so I wouldn't expect the configuration to work across both based on the information you have provided in the question.

Comment: @serpent5 Ah I see. No, this unit of work is based in one of my controllers. I passed a DI instance of _mapper to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scanning through the project, I noticed that somewhere in previous documentation - I read about creating a type of "config" class that just inherits from an abstract class called Profile. In this class you will also be able to define your maps, yet what is strange is that I am not able to drop this class and simply use the config maps setup in my Startup.cs file. Automapper will refuse to hold any maps that are not defined in this separate class. The below seems to get me what I need, however I still need an explanation as to why Automapper doesn't function as desired without it:

```
public class AMConfig : Profile
{
    public AMConfig()
    {
        CreateMap<ManageUserModel, IndexViewModel>();
        CreateMap<IndexViewModel, ManageUserModel>();
        CreateMap<NotificationViewModel, NotificationModel>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<List<NotificationViewModel>, List<NotificationModel>>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<TaskViewModel, TaskModel>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```